# How do I install Google Apps 20130812 into CyanogenMod 10.1 (Android 4.2.2)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, clockworkmod-recovery, google-apps, samsung-fascinate

I am attempting to install the [Google Apps (gapps) 20130812 update](http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip) for Android 4.2.2 on my Samsung Galaxy Fascinate which is running [CyanogenMod 10.1-20130723-NIGHTLY-fascinatemtd](http://get.cm/?device=fascinatemtd&type=nightly) utilizing ClockworkMod v4.0.1.0. I have pushed the gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip file to the device's SD-Card.

Once I have booted into ClockworkMod I select `install zip from sdcard` then `chosse zip from sdcard` then select `gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip` and confirm that I am sure I want to install. ClockworkMod then goes through the process of installing Google Apps for Android 4.2.2 and indicates that it succeeded in doing so.

[image: screenshot of install screen]

When I reboot the Fascinate none of the gapps are listed. What am I missing? How do I install Google Apps 20130812 into CyanogenMod 10.1 (Android 4.2.2)?

Comment: You mean, after the installation you boot into phone and there is no google market?

Comment: @Rat2000 exactly. After installing in ClockworkMod and rebooting into CyanogenMod there are no Google Apps, market or otherwise.

Comment: And you are positive that the installation finishes successfully? I mean this is very strange what you are saying here. In the thread from where you downloaded the app, isn't there any gapps posted? mayby you need another link or smth

Comment: @Rat2000 is there a way to take a screenshot while running ClockworkMod? If not I can just take a picture of the phone.

Comment: No you do not need to take a picture, if you read on the screen that the instalation was successful I belive you. Did you try and download the gapps again from the website?

Comment: In CWM recovery try going into Mounts menu and mounting the /system partition before flashing the gapps zip.

Comment: @Chahk when I tried to mount `/system` I received the message `Error mounting /system!`. Regardless I tried to install the gapps again and as you might expect it did not work.

Comment: @Rat2000 I decided to upload a picture because there are some other messages accompanying the installation success message. Those messages appear when I load the install from zip screen.

Comment: Mayby it would be better if you reinstall CM completle, wipe dalvik cache and partitions and download again gapps and install it.

Comment: Error while mounting /system partition is *bad*.  I would also recommend starting clean.  Also, it would be beneficial to check if there is an updated version of the Recovery image for your Fascinate available.

Comment: @Rat2000 I am using jt1134's ClockworkMod Recovery which is recommended on [CyanogemMod page for installing CM on a Fascinate device](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_fascinatemtd). Is there a better version of ClockworkMod I should be using?

Comment: @Chahk where can I find recent Recovery images for my Fascinate? As [indicated above](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53087/how-do-i-install-google-apps-20130812-into-cyanogenmod-10-1-android-4-2-2#comment71385_53087) not having a ton of luck with my Googlfu.

Comment: Good question.  The latest version on the [official page](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager) seems to be even older than the one you are using (3.0.0.8), but I'd try that anyway.  Try the version from [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=942021).  Worst case - you can always [revert back to stock](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=782204) and start again.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. Apparently when you boot into recovery with the 3-button-method, you can't install zips. No idea why.

Solutions to try:

1. Enable `Reboot into Recovery` in Power Menu. First, enable `Developer Options` by going to `Settings > About phone > tap Build number a bunch of times`. Then go to `Settings > Developer Options > Advanced Reboot`. Then power down and select `Reboot into Recovery`. This option never appeared on the Power Menu for me. No idea why.
2. Use ADB to reboot into recovery. Enable USB (Android) debugging via `Developer Options`. I gave root access to Apps and ADB also. Plug device into USB port on laptop with ADB. Enter this into your terminal:

   ```
   adb reboot recovery
   ```

If you haven't installed ADB, I would try here first if you're on Ubuntu or Debian: [http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_adb_intro](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc%3a_adb_intro)

Comment: actually the option number 2 worked where you have to enable the recovery from power menu than it will flash successfully and all will be well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "Error mounting /system" line seems a bit off as I believe that's where the gapps update is applied. If you mount /system manually, what happens? You'll find the option at 'mounts and storage' > '- mount /system'

If you're successful in mounting it, try installing the gapps zip file again.

Comment: It fails when trying to mount. That error is left over from trying to manually mount.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to flash back to Factory Rom (EH03 Gingerbread). Reinstalled CWM and SU, then flashed CM 10.1 once more from SD Card.  CWM returns to boot option menu after install, at which point I installed gapps BEFORE rebooting into fresh flash of 10.1 - Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

Do you aware of these,
***20130812***

**MD5: 5f22f046e37038a3856eeb825e73d4ed**

Not compatible with 4.3.x!

Not recommended for 4.2.1.

Does not include GalleryGoogle, meaning no Photosphere-equipped Camera app.

**Gmail added to package (for those who could not download through Play Store) and updated to 4.5.2-714156.**

Google+ added to package (to fix Location map tiles bug) and updated to 4.1.0.50809204.

Google Play Services updated to 3.2.25.

Google Play Store updated to 4.3.11.

Google Search updated to 2.6.7.721924.

TalkBack updated to 3.4.0.

for more details please refer this [link](http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps#20130812)

Comment: He is installing the correct package

Comment: I got that issue when moving from c10.0.1 to 0.2.
I have to re-flash it and worked for me. Try it now.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if you managed to resolve this but I had the same problem and found a fix.
First, I had to flash using rt4formatter, then mount /system and then flash the google apps. This worked for some of my google services but still missing google play and and other things. Only gmail and calender were installed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not resolved the issue. In fact I think I bricked the phone in the process and have not got back around to trying to fix. When I Googled *rt4formatter* I only found this page. Do you have a link to it?

Comment: This doesn't seem like much of a fix if it only installed Gmail and Google calendar (and I also cannot find this "rt4formatter" anywhere on the Internet).